# Powershell How to remove specific characters within a text

Tags: powershell, replace, special-characters

Below is the text for which I want to remove specific characters

```
$testChars = '[{"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"I have submitted for Approval"|
    "user":"UserName2","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 13:14:21 GMT","action":"APPROVED","comme
    nt":"This has been approved......"|"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"I have submitted for Approval"|"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"This is rejected"}]'
```

From this string, I want to remove the below 6 characters

```
'
{ 
}
[
]
"
```

I want to retain all other text/symbols like colon and pipe symbol.
I have tried below code, to replace the characters with empty"" but does not work for me:

```
 $newVal= $testChars -Replace "\[\{\}\]",""
```

Comment: Use a regex OR (pipe character between each atom that you want to match: "\[|\{|\}|\]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex for character replacement:

```
$newVal = $testChars -replace "\[|\]|\{|\}|`"|'"
```

Simplified further using a set:

```
$newVal = $testChars -replace '[[\]{}''"]'
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine

Comment: @OwainEsau Regex definitely has its place.  In capturing special characters like this, it's tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a hash table for these sorts of things:

```
$testChars = '[{"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"I have submitted for Approval"|
    "user":"UserName2","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 13:14:21 GMT","action":"APPROVED","comme
    nt":"This has been approved......"|"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"I have submitted for Approval"|"user":"UserName1","date":"Fri, 15 Dec 2017 12:31:03 GMT","
    action":"Submitted","comment":"This is rejected"}]'



 $hash = @{}
 $hash.'{' = ''
 $hash."'" = ""
 $hash.'}' = ''
 $hash.'[' = ''
 $hash.']' = ''
 $hash.'"' = ''

 Foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
    $testChars = $testChars.Replace($key, $hash.$key)
 }
 $testChars
```

Should give you the results you are after.